# How to grep with a regex to eliminate this stacktrace?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I would like to eliminate a stacktrace from my log file, such that only the SQL text is displayed. This works as I would like on RegExr.com:

`'java.lang((.|\n)*)java:745'`

But it does not work with `grep -v`

`grep -v 'java.lang((.|\n)*)java:745'`

Any suggestions how I can use `grep -v` to only display the query text?

```
CONFIG: 204658E4 SQL: select  *  
        from    table
        where   column =  :1 
java.lang.Throwable: No Error
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1624)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4347)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4426)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:4733)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyFactory.invoke(PreparedStatementProxyFactory.java:125)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sqlj.runtime.ExecutionContext$OracleContext.oracleExecuteQuery(ExecutionContext.java:71)
    at me.loadQuery(DataBean.java:364)
    at me.loadQuery(DataBean.java:411)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.secure.navigate_jsp.displayMenu(navigate_jsp.java:43)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.secure.navigate_jsp._jspService(navigate_jsp.java:472)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Maybe you can remove all lines starting with `java.lang.Throwable` or `    at` (4 spaces before at)?

Comment: thanks! this worked, maybe post as answer?  `grep -v 'java.lang.*\|.*at.*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your given output, you can see that the the Java exception follows a very specific pattern:

- the line with the error message, **starting with** `java.lang.Throwable`
- the stacktrace lines, all **starting with 0 or more spaces, followed by** `at`

Using `grep` to filter the lines, we can see from the man page, that you only need to specify a part of the line to dismiss it (when using the `-v` flag to ignore lines matching the pattern).

So based on that, we can build the regular expression and the command:

```
grep -v '^java.lang.Throwable\| *at' your_log_file.log
```

- `^<expression>` The expression must match a the beginning of the line
- `<expr1>\|<expr2>` The expression matches if `expr1` **OR** `expr2` matches.
- `java.lang.Throwable` matches this exact string
- `*at` can be decomposed in 2:

  - `*` (a space followed by a `*`) matches any number of spaces (0 or more)
  - `at` matches this exact string

So to sum it up, it will ignore all the lines that starts by either `java.lang.Throwable` or any number of spaces followed by `at`.